# Audio does not play after click event

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-audio

I'm developing music player for live streaming radio on my organization's website. But the audio is not played after clicking the play button.
My code, including the CSS:

```js
function playSound(sound) {
  var song1 = document.querySelector('.play');
  song1.volume = .50;
  if (song1.paused) {
    song1.mainkan();
  } else {
    song1.pause();
  }
  if (song1.paused) {
    document.getElementById("mainkan")
  } else {
    document.getElementById("mainkan")
  }
}

const play = document.querySelector('.play');
play.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.target.classList.toggle('pause');
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: -10px auto 0 auto;
  height: 400px;
  width: 320px;
}

.circle {
  /* Draw circles */
  border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.animated {
  /* Smoother animations */
  transform: translateZ(0);
}


/* tower */

.tower {
  position: absolute;
  top: 12.5%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: -30px 0 0 0;
}

.tower .signal {
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  left: 46.8%;
  margin: 0px 0 0 -15px;
}

.tower .signal .rings {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 7px double #27738B;
  animation: scale 1s infinite linear;
}

.tower .dot {
  margin: 10px auto -7px auto;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #27738B;
}

.tower .triangle {
  margin: 5px auto 0 auto;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 30px solid #27738B;
}


/* player */

.player {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -120px 0 0 -120px;
  height: 240px;
  width: 240px;
  background-color: #27738B;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.play {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  margin-top: 80px;
  margin-left: 92px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 40px 0px 40px 70px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent white;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
}

.pause {
  border-style: double;
  border-width: 0px 0px 0px 60px;
}

.player .buffering {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  width: 230px;
  height: 230px;
  border-right: 5px solid #5C8596;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #5C8596;
  border-left: 5px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-top: 5px solid #FFFFFF;
  animation: rotate 5s infinite linear;
}


/* text */

.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 85%;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #C1B8B8;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 100%;
  animation: pulse 1.3s infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="tower">
    <div class="signal">
      <div class="rings circle animated">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dot circle"></div>
    <div class="triangle"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="player circle">
    <div class="buffering circle animated"></div>
    <audio id="sound" controls>
      <source src="http://stream.zeno.fm/6hegrghq2p8uv">
    </audio>

    <div class="play" id="mainkan" onclick="playSound('sound')"></div>
```

Comment: where is your CSS code??

Comment: You have multiple elements with the same id (sound). That's not allowed. Fix that and then edit your code above.

Comment: I have css but this is my first time using Stackoverlfow because too many css so can't submit question with long code, sorry

Comment: I have add css sir, you can read again

Answer (score 0):

There isnt any code there to tell the audio element to start playing.

Try this

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="tower">
            <div class="signal">
              <div class="rings circle animated"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="dot circle"></div>
            <div class="triangle"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="player circle">
            <div class="buffering circle animated"></div>
            <audio id="sound">
              <source src="http://stream.zeno.fm/6hegrghq2p8uv">
            </audio>
        <div class="play"></div>
        <script>
            const play = document.querySelector('.play');
            play.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
                 // Get the audio element first
                 const audio = document.querySelector('#sound');
                 // Call the play method on the audio element
                 audio.play();
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for help!

Comment: Glad to help. Consider accepting one of the answers from me or others if it works out for you.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you must have something like this:

```
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="tower">
      <div class="signal">
        <div class="rings circle animated">
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class="dot circle"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
</div>
      <div class="player circle">
        <div class="buffering circle animated"></div>
          <audio id="sound" controls>
            <source src="http://stream.zeno.fm/6hegrghq2p8uv">
          </audio>

      <div class="play" >Play</div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    const play = document.querySelector('.play');
    const music = document.querySelector('#sound');
    let flag = false;

    play.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
    e.target.classList.toggle('pause');
    if(!flag){
      music.play();
    flag = true;
    play.textContent = 'pause';
  }else{
    music.pause();
    play.textContent = 'play';
    flag = false;
    }
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Okay I will try

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```js
function playSound(sound) {
       var song1 = document.querySelector('#sound');
       song1.volume = .50;
       if (song1.paused) {
           song1.play();
       } else if (song1.play){
           song1.pause();
       }
   }

    const play = document.querySelector('.play');
    play.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
    e.target.classList.toggle('pause');
  })
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin: -10px auto 0 auto;
    height: 400px;
    width: 320px;
}
.circle {
    /* Draw circles */
    border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.animated {
    /* Smoother animations */
    transform: translateZ(0);
}

/* tower */
.tower {
    position: absolute;
    top: 12.5%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: -30px 0 0 0;
}
.tower .signal {
    position: absolute;
    top: -3px;
    left: 46.8%;
    margin: 0px 0 0 -15px;
}
.tower .signal .rings {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 7px double #27738B;
    animation: scale 1s infinite linear;
}
.tower .dot {
    margin: 10px auto -7px auto;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: #27738B;
}
.tower .triangle {
    margin: 5px auto 0 auto;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 30px solid #27738B;
}

/* player */
.player {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -120px 0 0 -120px;
    height: 240px;
    width: 240px;
    background-color: #27738B;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.play {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  margin-top: 80px;
  margin-left: 92px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 40px 0px 40px 70px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent white;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
}

.pause {
  border-style: double;
  border-width:0px 0px 0px 60px;
}

.player .buffering {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    width: 230px;
    height: 230px;
    border-right: 5px solid #5C8596;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #5C8596;
    border-left: 5px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-top: 5px solid #FFFFFF;
    animation: rotate 5s infinite linear;
}

/* text */
.text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 85%;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #C1B8B8;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 100%;
    animation: pulse 1.3s infinite;
}
#sound{
    display: none;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="tower">
          <div class="signal">
            <div class="rings circle animated">
          </div>
        </div>
      <div class="dot circle"></div>
      <div class="triangle"></div>
      </div>
          <div class="player circle">
            <div class="buffering circle animated"></div>
              <audio id="sound" controls>
                <source src="http://stream.zeno.fm/6hegrghq2p8uv">
              </audio>

          <div class="play" id="mainkan" onclick="playSound('sound')"></div>
```

Full code:

```
<style>
body {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin: -10px auto 0 auto;
    height: 400px;
    width: 320px;
}
.circle {
    /* Draw circles */
    border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.animated {
    /* Smoother animations */
    transform: translateZ(0);
}

/* tower */
.tower {
    position: absolute;
    top: 12.5%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: -30px 0 0 0;
}
.tower .signal {
    position: absolute;
    top: -3px;
    left: 46.8%;
    margin: 0px 0 0 -15px;
}
.tower .signal .rings {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 7px double #27738B;
    animation: scale 1s infinite linear;
}
.tower .dot {
    margin: 10px auto -7px auto;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: #27738B;
}
.tower .triangle {
    margin: 5px auto 0 auto;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 30px solid #27738B;
}

/* player */
.player {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -120px 0 0 -120px;
    height: 240px;
    width: 240px;
    background-color: #27738B;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.play {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  margin-top: 80px;
  margin-left: 92px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 40px 0px 40px 70px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent white;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
}

.pause {
  border-style: double;
  border-width:0px 0px 0px 60px;
}

.player .buffering {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    width: 230px;
    height: 230px;
    border-right: 5px solid #5C8596;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #5C8596;
    border-left: 5px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-top: 5px solid #FFFFFF;
    animation: rotate 5s infinite linear;
}

/* text */
.text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 85%;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #C1B8B8;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 100%;
    animation: pulse 1.3s infinite;
}
#sound{
    display: none;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
        <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="tower">
          <div class="signal">
            <div class="rings circle animated">
          </div>
        </div>
      <div class="dot circle"></div>
      <div class="triangle"></div>
      </div>
          <div class="player circle">
            <div class="buffering circle animated"></div>
              <audio id="sound" controls>
                <source src="http://stream.zeno.fm/6hegrghq2p8uv">
              </audio>

          <div class="play" id="mainkan" onclick="playSound('sound')"></div>

    <script>
    function playSound(sound) {
       var song1 = document.querySelector('#sound');
       song1.volume = .50;
       if (song1.paused) {
           song1.play();
       } else if (song1.play){
           song1.pause();
       }
   }

    const play = document.querySelector('.play');
    play.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
    e.target.classList.toggle('pause');
  })
</script>
    </body>
              </html>
```